# Xamarin Forms Slider in ListView in TabbedPage not sliding correctly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a DataTemplate that puts a slider inside a ListView within a TabbedPage. On Android the slider does not move correctly and sliding left to right activates the TabbedPage sliding feature. If the slider is outside the ListView it works correctly. How can I prevent parent controls of the slider from handling the drag gesture?

The method ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean) may be of help but which renderer etc would I do this?

[Video of issue with the slider](https://youtu.be/xgoAyg244Vs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `SliderRenderer`, and then call the `RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)` in `DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)`, it can solve this problem, here is my code:

`MainPage`:

```
        var tabsXaml = new TabbedPage { Title = "Working with ListView" };
        tabsXaml.Children.Add(new BasicListXaml { Title = "Basic", Icon = "icon.png" } );
        tabsXaml.Children.Add(new JustView { Title = "JustView", Icon = "icon.png" });
        tabsXaml.Children.Add(new UnevenRowsXaml { Title = "UnevenX", Icon = "icon.png" });
        tabsXaml.Children.Add(new SliderPage { Title = "SliderPage", Icon = "icon.png" });
        MainPage = tabsXaml;
```

The SecondPage in `TabbedPage`:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:MyListView x:Name="listView" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
        <local:MyListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <local:MySlider HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:MyListView.ItemTemplate>
    </local:MyListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

`SlidererRenderer`:

```
   public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);                    
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                 //This is the core of the problem!!!
                Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }
```

You must call  `RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` method. The `Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent` in my code means the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PageRenderer`, The reason that the `Slider` cannt work right in the [video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249147/xamarin-forms-slider-in-listview-in-tabbedpage-not-sliding-correctly) is that the `page`(in my code is JustView) prevent the slider from handling the drag gesture.

[image]

Comment: Great answer! You saved me from pulling all my hair out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I base my answer on the solution provided by York Shen. I didn't like the way parent nesting was hard-coded, so I just added a function to help find the renderer on which we want to call `RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent`. My Slider was nested in another view, which means I needed a different level parent. So here you go:

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            (_navigationPage ??= GetNavigationPage(Parent)).RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            //This is the core of the problem!!!
            _navigationPage.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
}

private IViewParent _navigationPage;

private IViewParent GetNavigationPage(IViewParent parent)
{
    if (parent is NavigationPageRenderer)
        return parent;
    return GetNavigationPage(parent.Parent);
}
```